# Fetch data from Json array in rows and columns

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have this query to append the arrary in JSON:

```
DECLARE @TheTable table(TheJSON nvarchar(max), Condition int )
DECLARE @mystring nvarchar(100)='{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}'

INSERT INTO @TheTable SELECT '[{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"}]', 1

UPDATE @TheTable 
SET TheJSON = JSON_MODIFY(TheJSON, 'append $', JSON_QUERY(N'{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}')) 
WHERE Condition = 1;

SELECT TheJSON FROM @TheTable
```

It gives me the output in 1 single Row:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"},{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}]
```

Till this part it is correct.

Now I want to fetch the data from this table in rows and columns wise like a regular table:

```
ID  Name    
1   One 
2   Two 
3   Three
```

How to fetch the data from Json in rows and columns wise?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For SQL server, you can use OPENJSON to parse JSON to table - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TheTable table(TheJSON nvarchar(max), Condition int )
DECLARE @mystring nvarchar(100)='{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}'

INSERT INTO @TheTable SELECT '[{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"}]', 1

UPDATE @TheTable 
SET TheJSON = JSON_MODIFY(TheJSON, 'append $', JSON_QUERY(N'{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}')) 
WHERE Condition = 1;

SELECT @mystring =  TheJSON FROM @TheTable

SELECT  p.*
    FROM 
    OPENJSON (@mystring, '$') WITH(id varchar(10) '$.id', name varchar (30) '$.name') p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mystring nvarchar(100)='{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}'

INSERT INTO @TheTable SELECT '[{"id": 1, "name": "One"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Two"}]', 1

UPDATE @TheTable 
SET TheJSON = JSON_MODIFY(TheJSON, 'append $', JSON_QUERY(N'{"id": 3, "name": "Three"}')) 
WHERE Condition = 1;

Declare @temp nvarchar(max)

select @temp= TheJSON   FROM @TheTable     

select id,name   FROM OPENJSON(@temp)                              
 WITH (                              
 id  NVARCHAR(100)  ,                            
 name   NVARCHAR(100)                                                    

 )
```

Hi you can try this. This is giving what you want . Thank you.